How to get user claims from Keycloak Admin console, using the java code SPI implementation without passing Access token explicitely
I am Implementing the SPI, which triggers on user create update or delete event and stores the user data in form of userDetails, roles, permissions, claims in the Redis cache, how to get the user claims for a particular user, on updating the user or creating it using SPI without explicitely passing the bearer token as everything should be extracted from the Keycloak Admin console for that user.
I tried this way but got nothing from this, User Session was coming null and userSessionModel was also coming null
public Map<String, String> getClaims(UserModel user) {
Map<String, String> claims = new HashMap<>();
UserSessionModel userSessionModel = session.sessions().getUserSession(realm, user.getId());
AuthorizationRequest request = new AuthorizationRequest();
Map<String, List> originalClaims = request.getClaims();
log.info("originalClaims: " + originalClaims);
originalClaims.forEach((key, values) -> {
log.info("key: " + key + ", values: " + values);
String value = values.isEmpty() ? null : values.get(0);
claims.put(key, value);
});
log.info("claims: " + claims);
return claims;
}

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
